# Microsoft Clarity: Why “Unique users” is greater than “Total sessions”

Tags: statistics, google-analytics

This image is screenshot of my Microsoft Clarity panel. As you see, "Distinct users" number is greater than "Total sessions" number!
[image]

Is this a bug or there is something else that I don't know?
(I'm sorry for select `google-analytics` tag, because there isn't `microsoft-clarity` tag)

Comment: Maybe a bug, or maybe users that didn't manage to start a session?

Comment: @harrymc "users that didn't manage to start a session", Is that possible??

Comment: I don't know Microsoft Clarity enough to answer.